# How to assign the existing products of one website to another?

Tags: magento-1

I have a Magento installation which has multiple website.
Now I want to assign some configurable and simple products to the another newly created website which is using same Root category as other websites.

Do I need to reimport the products? or I can map using sku,website and store id?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert new products to the table `catalog_product_website`.
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` VALUES (`product_id`, `website_id`) VALUES ($productId, $newWebsiteId), ($productId2, $newWebsiteId) ...
```

Comment: Do we have any option using import?

Comment: Maybe try to specify new `website_id` in import file for each desired product